# WCF: tcp service timeout when I transfer a file

Tags: wcf, tcp

I have a WCF service, that use tcp for the communication. When I try to transfer a file from the client to the service, if I do that in the same computerm in which the configure file in the client and in the service use the localhost for the url, I have not any problem.

However, if I try to do the same when the client is in other computer in the lan, I get the following exception:

System.TimeoutException: This request operation sent to net.tcp://192.168.1.5:7997/CMMSHost did not receive a reply within the configured timeout (00:01:00).  The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.  This may be because the service is still processing the operation or because the service was unable to send a reply message.  Please consider increasing the operation timeout (by casting the channel/proxy to IContextChannel and setting the OperationTimeout property) and ensure that the service is able to connect to the client.

however, if I try to use other actions, such as search information or add registers and any other kind of operation, the application works fine.

So the problem is in the transfer of the file.

In the service I use this configuration:

```
<endpoint address=""
                  binding="netTcpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="tcpBinding"
                  name="NetTcpBindingEndpoint"
                  contract="GTS.CMMS.Service.IService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>

        <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexTcpBinding" address="net.tcp://localhost:5000/mex" />
      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="behaviorConfig">
          <!--
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />-->
          <!--Necesario para poder enviar excepciones desde el servicio al cliente.-->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="100" maxConcurrentSessions="100" />
          <serviceMetadata/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>


    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="tcpBinding" maxBufferSize="67108864"
                      maxReceivedMessageSize="67108864" maxBufferPoolSize="67108864"
                       transferMode="Buffered" closeTimeout="00:00:10"
                       openTimeout="00:00:10" receiveTimeout="00:20:00"
                       sendTimeout="00:01:00" maxConnections="100">
          <security mode="None"/>
          <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="67108864" maxBytesPerRead="67108864" maxStringContentLength="67108864"/>
          <reliableSession enabled="true" inactivityTimeout="00:20:00" />
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

And in the client:

```
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="NetTcpBinding_IService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
          openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
          transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
          hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="10" maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
          maxBufferSize="65536" maxConnections="10" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
            maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:20:00"
            enabled="true" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
            <messa
```

ge clientCredentialType="Windows" />

Thanks.

Comment: I see that your binding has the sentTimeout to be "00:01:00", try changing that to a larger value. Also if you are transfering files that are larger than 4MB consider increasing the readerQuotas to larger values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your application is working well for small size file in kbs? if yes then for lager size file use transferMode="Streamed" instead of transferMode="Buffered". You have to change configuration accordingly.

If your application is not working for even smaller files there is a problem with your application.
Build your application and regenerate proxy and try to debug your application.

You can also refer these links
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/166763/WCF-Streaming-Upload-Download-Files-Over-HTTP
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33825/WCF-TCP-based-File-Server